# how to fetch content of xml element using idref

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML schema:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="unqualified">

 <xsd:element name="Person">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

   <xsd:element name="Book">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Author">
               <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="idref" type="xsd:IDREF" 
                                 use="required"/>
               </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element  ref="Person" />
                <xsd:element  ref="Book" />
         </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>       
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

and corresponding to above XML schema, I have following incoming XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<root>

  <Person id="P234">
      <Name>0002</Name>
    </Person> 
<Book>
     <Title>0001</Title>
    <Author idref="P234"/>
    </Book>

 </root>
```

I know using XML parser validation, I can validate if above XML conforms to my XML schema.for e.g. id and idref should be present. Now what I want to know is which parser(SAX/DOM/STAX) can fetch me complete XML element based on idref. So basically in above example, `once parser reaches idref="P234", it should return me complete <Person>...</Person>`. Another query is does any parser support id and idref merging, which can replace content of idref with actual element and return me merged XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsers don't do it, as I know. Use XSLT to do the magic. Moreover, idrefs could be self-referenced, have a cyclic dependency, so it's impossible just "replace content with actual element".

E.g. say you have the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<root>
    <Person id="P234">
        <Name>0002</Name>
        <WroteBook idref="B442"/>
    </Person> 
    <Book id="B442">
        <Title>0001</Title>
        <Author idref="P234"/>
    </Book>
</root>
```

What would you expect from a parser?

An XSLT (not tested myself however):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@idref">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="id(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what is actual usage of id and idref if parsers don't have any features around it. what is practical need of specifying id and idref in case we don't use XSLT. Also can you please elaborate on how to do magic with XSLT. Thanks.

Comment: It's a way to express references between elements, parsers only check validity, so that an XML consumer of the validated document will be sure if all refs are resolved. There is no any other way to express it in an XSD. Also, some other xml technologies have the notion of ID, e.g. the DOM has getElementById method.